# UIButton does not fire target on touchUpInside unless I drag just outside?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton, selector

I have a Button that when I press it, it does not fire the target selector that I've added. I've made the button Different Images, so I can see that I am Pressing it.

So here is the Funny if I Press, and drag outside of the button, but not outside of the button's immediate superView, the target selector is fired!

I've also in testing set the setClipsToBounds:YES on all the super/sub views just to be sure it was still in the views bounds.  Seems to be within bounds.  The dragging outside the button area seems to be omni directional, so its not like I can only tap/drag right. Left up and down work too. I can tap, drag out then back in and it works. If I don't start to drag and just tap and hold, the button highlights and then goes back to unselected state.

Here is the code for the Button.  The Button is on a UIView along with a UITextView, Actually onTop Of the UITextView. The UIView that all of this is on is on a Larger View, which is on a Scaling/Scrolling view

```
        messageLookupButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 21, 20)];
        [messageLookupButton setTitle:@"junk" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [messageLookupButton sizeToFit];
        [messageLookupButton setTag:kGearButtonView];

            //Get the images for the buttons
        UIImage *gearButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gear.png"];
        UIImage *gearButtonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StatusLightOn.png"];

        [messageLookupButton setImage:gearButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [messageLookupButton setImage:gearButtonImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [messageLookupButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gearPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(processLookupResults:)
                                                     name:kRefreshFromPopover object:nil];
        [self addSubview: messageLookupButton ];
        [messageLookupButton release];

        [messageLookupButton setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(elementViewContents.bounds)  -kElementContentFrameOffset  -(CGRectGetWidth( messageLookupButton.bounds)/2), CGRectGetMidY(elementViewContents.bounds))];


        [self bringSubviewToFront:messageLookupButton];
```

The Scroll View has several gesture recognizers on it. Though they don't seem to interfere with other buttons and controls that I've put on the screen.  Though I have a feeling its the Scroll View that is the problem.

scroll view code clip:

```
[scrollContentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[scrollContentView setExclusiveTouch:YES];
[scrollContentView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
[scrollContentView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up Just adding the gear as an Image to the View, then created a invisible button that was the same size as the UIView that I placed the gear icon on.

```
-(void) addMessageLookupSelector {
        // Set a default Color if there is none
    if (_isMessageLookupField ){
            // Add Gear to End Of Text Field
        if (!messageLookupImageView) {
            messageLookupImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 21, 20)];
            [messageLookupImageView setTag:kGearButtonView];
            [messageLookupImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear.png"] ];

            [self addSubview: messageLookupImageView ];
            [messageLookupImageView release];
        }
        [self positionMessageLookupImageView ];      
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}



    - (void)makeControlEditable {

            //Setup the TextField so we can edit its value, need to see if there is a Write Animation Assocated with Element
        [self setTheWriteTag];
        if (writeTag) {
            writeInputRequestedButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [writeInputRequestedButton setFrame:elementViewContents.frame];
            [writeInputRequestedButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [writeInputRequestedButton setEnabled:YES];
                // [writeInputRequestedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [self addSubview: writeInputRequestedButton];
            [self bringSubviewToFront:writeInputRequestedButton];
            [writeInputRequestedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wantsToEditValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
```